# Google Plus button load by ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-plus

I've got problem with my website "http://szymondziewonski.com/" , I want to load google plus button with

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
        {
            parsetags: 'explicit';
        }
    </script>
```

And then, put this script in place which is loaded.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">gapi.plusone.go(".googlePlusHomePage .special");</script>
```

It works good mostly someitimes i get error in developers tool, console.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null

So that error is my first problem problem

**And second problem is wc3** validate

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fszymondziewonski.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

The text content of element script was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found { instead.

*Syntax of script documentation:
Zero or more code comments, each of which is either a single-line comment starting with "//" or a multi-line comment starting with "/*" and ending with "*/". The content must also meet the constraints of the script microsyntax. For further details, see Inline documentation for external scripts*

So, some1 know how to work around that? only with google button there is so much problems. 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `;` at the end of your `parsetags` line. That should be removed to look like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js">
  {parsetags: 'explicit'}
</script>
```

I have not tested it but you might be able to set parsetags to explicit like this and avoid the validation error:

```
<script>
  window.___gcfg = {
    parsetags: 'explicit'
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, still w3c has problem to validate this, but I don't have error's so thank you, any idea to work around validation? Because I'd like to have clean sheet valdiation :)

Comment: It appears as though the example code is not compliant with [recommended HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-script-element.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts). I don't know if it'll work but you might be able to set a different param to get rid of the validation error.

Comment: It WORKS! THANK YOU :) If I could buy a beer I would :) Thanks bro